# Wrong use of 'file of char'

Tags: pascal

Im having problems with this code, I have two file of char, one is filed with information about books, and the other is empty, i have to write in SAL some information from S and then show the total of how many books match the first 2 digits of the code and how many are R and how many are T. The code, does write the information form S to Sal, but when its supposed to show the totals it appears ERORR 100 on screen. I read about it and it says that it is a problem with 'Disk read error' and that *This error typically occurs, if you "seed" a non-existent record of a typed file and try to read/write it. *, i really dont undertand.

I've benn trying to figure it out, but I haven't been able to. I notice that if I dont put 'WHILE NOT EOF(S) DO' the error does not appear, but of course i need the while, if someone is able to point out my mistakes i would really apreciate it.

This is the code:

```
uses crt;

var 
i : byte;
s,sal: file of char;
v,l1,l2: char;
cs,cn,cl: integer;

pn,ps,tot: integer;

BEGIN
 cs:=0; cn:=0;  i:=0; cl:=0;
Assign (s, 'C:\Users\te\Documents\s.txt');
     {$I-}
     Reset (s);
     {$I+}
     if IOResult <> 0 then
     begin
       writeln('Error');
       halt(2);  
     end;

      Assign (sal, 'C:\Users\te\Documents\sal.txt');
     {$I-}
     Rewrite (sal);
     IOResult;
     {$I+}
     if IOResult <> 0 then
       halt(2);  


    writeln('Please write the code of the book, only 2 digits');
    read(L1);read(L2);
    read(s,v);

    while (not eof(s)) do
    begin

      for i:=1 to 2 do
      read(s,v);

      if (v = '0') then
      begin
      read(s,v);
        if (v = '1') or (v = '2') then
        begin

        for i:=1 to 5 do
        read(s,v);

        if (v = 'R') then
        begin
        read(s,v);
        cs:= cs + 1;
        end
        else
        begin

        if (v = 'T') then
        begin
        cn:= cn + 1;
        read(s,v);
        end;
      end;

      while (v <> '-') do
      read(s,v);
      while (v = '-') do
      read(s,v);

      if (v = L1) then
      begin
      write(sal, v);
      read(s,v);
       if (v = L2)  then
       begin
       write(sal,v);
       read(s,v);
       cl:= cl + 1;
       end;
      end;

      while ( v <> '/') do
      begin
      write(sal,v);
      read(s,v);
      end;
      write(sal, '-');
      end

      else
      begin
      for i:= 1 to 5 do
      read(s,v);

      if (v = 'R') then
      cs:= cs + 1
      else
      cn:= cn + 1;

      if (v = L1) then
      read(s,v);
      if (v = L2) then
      begin
      cl:= cl + 1;
      read(s,v);
     end;
    end;

     end


     else
     begin
     for i:= 1 to 5 do
     read(s,v);

     if (v = 'R') then
     cs:= cs + 1
     else
     cn:= cn + 1;

     if (v = L1) then
     read(s,v);
     if (v = L2) then
     begin
     cl:= cl + 1;
     read(s,v);
     end;
    end;
    end;



    tot:= cs + cn;
    ps:= (cs * 100) div tot;
    pn:= (cn * 100) div tot;



    writeln('TOTAL ',cl);
    writeln();
    writeln(ps,'% and',pn,'%');
```

The file S content:

```
02022013Rto kill a mockingbird-1301/02012014Tpeter pan-1001/02032013Thowto-2301/02012012Tmaze runner-1001/02012012Tmaze runner-1001/02012012Tmaze runner-1001/$
```

I really just need someone else's point of view on this code, I think maybe the algorithm is flawed. 
Thanks

Comment: Which Pascal version are you using?  FPC+Lazarus or what?

Comment: Is this on Windows or Linux?  Btw, I think you'd find Lazarus much more usable as a beginner than Geany.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that

Comment: The part `Assign (sal, 'C:\Users\sal.txt');  {$I-}  Rewrite (sal); IOResult; {$I+} if IOResult <> 0 then halt(2);` contains a subtle issue: If you get an error during rewrite, it is dropped  and the second IOResult will return no error, but ofcourse you cannot write. (This is at least the behavior for TurboPascal). Do you get an error / halt(2) if you change the code to `Assign (sal, 'C:\Users\sal.txt');  {$I-}  Rewrite (sal); if IOResult <> 0 then halt(2); {$I+}`?

Comment: I've had a look at your code and imo there are too many unknowns (e.g. does your `s.txt` contain Unicode or Ansi (characters which are each one bye long)).  It would be **far** easier if you use `Text` files instead of `file of char`.  Is that a change you could make, or is this coursework which requires you to use a `file of char`?

Comment: But Unicode or ANSI file of char?

Comment: I'm finding your code rather confusing, to say the least.  Given a book entry like `02022013Rto kill a mockingbird-1301`, which two characters of it are supposed to represent the 'book code' (L1, l2) you are looking for?

Comment: What is "fi och"? Why did you change the title? Originally, you had "file of Char" which sounds much better.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit as it invalidated both the question and the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(After your edit, i see that your code now compiles w/o error in FPC, so I'm glad you've managed to fix the error yourself)

<s>As this is obviously coursework, I'm not going to fix your code for you and in any case the way</s>Even so, I'm afraid you are going about this is completely wrong.

Basically, the main thing wrong with your code is that you are trying to control what happens as your read the source file character by character.  Quite frankly, that's a hopeless way of trying to do it, because it makes the execution flow unnecessarily complicated and littered with ifs, buts and loops.  It also requires you to keep mental track of what you are trying to do at any given step, and the resulting code is inherently **not** self-documenting - imagine if you came back to your code in six months, could you tell at a glance how it works and what it does?  I certsinly couldn't personally.

You need to break the task down in a different way.  Instead of analysing the problem from the bottom up ("If I read this character next, then what I need to do next is ...') do it from the top down: Although your input file is a `file of char`, it contains a series of strings, separated by a `/` character and finally terminated by a `$` (but this terminator does not really matter).  So what you need to do is to read these strings one-by-one; once you've got one, check whether it's the one you're looking for: if it is. process it however you need to, otherwise read the next one until you reach the end of the file.

Once you have successfully read one of the book strings, you can then split it up into the various fields it's composed of.  The most useful function for doing this splitting is probably `Copy`, which lets you extract substrings from a string - look it up in the FPC help.  I've included functions `ExtractTitle` and `ExtractPreamble` which show you what you need to do to write similar functions to extract the T/R code and the numeric code which follows the hyphen.  Btw, if you need to ask a similar q in the future, it would be very helpful if you include a description of the layout and meaning of the various fields in the file.

So, what I'm going to show you is how to read the series of strings in your `S.Txt` by building them character-by-character.  In the code below, I do this using a function `GetNextBook` which I hope is reasonable self-explanatory.  The code uses this function in a `while` loop to fill the `BookRecord` string variable. Then, it simply writes the `BookRecord` to the console.  What your code should do, of course, is to process the `BookRecord` contents to see if it is the one you are looking for and then do whether the remainder of your task is.

I hope you will agree that the code below is a lot clearer, a lot shorter and will be a lot easier to extend in future than the code in your q.  They key to structuring a program this way is to break the program's task into a series of functions and procedures which each perform a single sub-task.  Writing the program that way makes it easier to "re-wire" the program to change what it does, without having to rewrite the innards of the functions/procedures.

```
program fileofcharproject;

uses crt;

const
  sContents = '02022013Rto kill a mockingbird-1301/02012014Tpeter pan-1001/02032013Thowto-2301/02012012Tmaze runner-1001/02012012Tmaze runner-1001/02012012Tmaze runner-1001/$';
  InputFileName = 'C:\Users\MA\Documents\S.Txt';
  OutputFileName = 'C:\Users\MA\Documents\Sal.Txt';

type
  CharFile = File of Char; //  this is to permit a file of char to be used
                           //  as a parameter to a function/procedure

function GetNextBook(var S : CharFile) : String;
var
  InputChar : Char;
begin
  Result := '';

  InputChar := Chr(0);
  while not Eof(S) do begin
    Read(S, InputChar);
    // next, check that the char we've read is not a '/'
    //  if it is a '/' then exit this while loop
    if (InputChar <> '/') then
      Result := Result + InputChar
    else
      Break;
  end;
end;

function ExtractBookTitle(BookRecord : String) : String;
var
  p : Integer;
begin
  Result := Copy(BookRecord, 10, Length(BookRecord));
  p := Pos('-', Result);
  if p > 0 then
      Result := Copy(Result, 1, p - 1);
end;

procedure AddToOutputFile(var OutputFile : CharFile; BookRecord : String);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to Length(BookRecord) do
    write(OutputFile, BookRecord[i]);
  write(OutputFile, '/');
end;

function ExtractPreamble(BookRecord : String) : String;
begin
  Result := Copy(BookRecord, 1, 8);
end;

function TitleMatches(PartialTitle, BookRecord : String) : Boolean;
begin
  Result := Pos(PartialTitle, ExtractBookTitle(BookRecord)) > 0;
end;

var
  i : Integer; //byte;
  s,sal: file of char;
  l1,l2: char;
  InputChar : Char;
  BookFound : Boolean;
  cs,cn,cl: integer;
  pn,ps,tot: integer;
  Contents : String;
  BookRecord : String;
  PartialTitle : String;
begin
  //  First, create S.Txt so we don't have to make any assumptions about
  //  its contents

  Contents := sContents;
  Assign(s, InputFileName);
  Rewrite(s);

  for i := 1 to Length(Contents) do begin
    write(s, Contents[i]);  // writes the i'th character of Contents to the file
  end;

  Close(s);

  cs:=0; cn:=0;  i:=0; cl:=0;

  //  Open the input file
  Assign (s, InputFileName);
  {$I-}
  Reset (s);
  {$I+}
  if IOResult <> 0 then
  begin
    writeln('Error');
    halt(2);
  end;

  //  Open the output file
  Assign (sal, OutputFileName);
  {$I-}
  Rewrite (sal);
  IOResult;
  {$I+}
  if IOResult <> 0 then
   halt(2);

  //  the following reads the BookRecords one-by-one and copies
  //  any of them which match the partial title to sal.txt

  writeln('Enter part of a book title, followed by [Enter]');
  readln(PartialTitle);
  while not Eof(s) do begin
    BookRecord := GetNextBook(S);
    writeln(BookRecord);
    writeln('Preamble : ', ExtractPreamble(BookRecord));
    writeln('Title : ', ExtractBookTitle(BookRecord));
    if TitleMatches(PartialTitle, BookRecord) then
      AddToOutputFile(sal, BookRecord);
  end;

  //  add file '$' to sal.txt
  write(sal, '$');

  Close(sal);
  Close(s);

  writeln('Done, press any key');
  readln;

end.
```

Comment: I'm going to add a couple of bits to the code probably later on this evening.  Meanwhile, please feel free to accept my answer by clicking the 'Tick' icon next to its top lefthand corner.

Comment: I've posted my updates to this, including functions which extract various parts of the `BookRecord`.  Hth

Comment: I noticed you un-accepted my answer.  Is there a problem with it?

Comment: Im sorry, I was in my phone and I take it away